# JIRA Groovy - Link issues from another project

Tags: groovy, jira, jira-plugin

We have a special Jira setup so that 1 Epic in our master project = 1 Jira project full of stories/bugs/etc (Governance/compliance wanted this)

Each Issue type has a custom column called 'Ideal days'

For each Epic to get the total estimated days we have a custom function that Sums all 'Ideal days' of issues linked to that Epic that are in the backlog (we manually do this).

With Groovy Runner can I auto-link all issues in a project (in the backlog) to an Epic?    Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to link issues without cloning them, you should use [`IssueLinkManager.getLinkCollection()`](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/javadoc/jira/5.0.5/reference/com/atlassian/jira/issue/link/IssueLinkManager.html#getLinkCollection%28com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue,%20com.atlassian.crowd.embedded.api.User%29).

The code should look something something like this:

```
IssueLinkManager issueLinkManager = ComponentManager.getInstance().getIssueLinkManager()

issueLinkManager.getLinkCollection(someIssue, yourUser).each() {
   it.getOutwardIssues("Some Link Name")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a built-in script that clones an issue and links it. You should be able to link based on that code: https://jamieechlin.atlassian.net/wiki/display/GRV/Built-In+Scripts#Built-InScripts-Clonesanissueandlinks